# Can I use native mqtt to connect to my mqtt broker without the use of websockets?

Tags: javascript, browserify, html, mqtt, paho

I have a mqtt broker which does not support websocket connection. I need to write an HTML webpage that will connect to the broker and publish a message string on it. Is it possible to not use websockets through my web page and still connect and publish data?  If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not connect to anything from with in a browser with anything other than HTTP or WebSockets.

A possible solution is to set up a separate WebSockets to MQTT bridge between the web page and the broker.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-do-Javascript-MQTT-clients-need-to-go-through-a-websocket-and-cannot-directly-establish-a-MQTT-connection-to-the-MQTT-broker

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-do-Javascript-MQTT-clients-need-to-go-through-a-websocket-and-cannot-directly-establish-a-MQTT-connection-to-the-MQTT-broker- I read in one of the comments that says browserfy? Any help on that?>

Comment: No, that won't change anything

Comment: So all the possible ways of using mqtt protocol uses web sockets and nothing else? Can I use any of these http://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-client-library-encyclopedia/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30624897/direct-mqtt-vs-mqtt-over-websocket/30625067#30625067  -  I read your comment here. Is this something relevent?

Comment: WebSockets are a way of connecting to a two way communication pipe, just like a normal TCP socket, but from within a web browser. If you want to use MQTT from within a browser, you need to use a WebSocket. If you are not within a web browser, you don't need WebSockets.

Comment: I am using this source to connect and publish to a mqtt borker - http://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-client-library-encyclopedia-mosquitto-php

Comment: I am using mqtt.fx to subscribe to the topic I published my earlier data. But I cannot see and messages that are published on my topic. Any help on this?